# Duplicate key voilation for comination of key as unique set

Tags: php, mysql

In my table I have create a combination of unique key (article, customer, price).

Now I need to insert csv into this table and if row is duplicate in I need to update.

```
        " INSERT INTO 
                `article` (`article`, `customer`, `price`, `a`, `b`) VALUES ()-- VALUES
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE article= VALUES(article), customer= VALUES(customer), price = VALUES(price), a = VALUES(a), b= VALUES(b) "



foreach ($values as $value) {

....
```

Each time when I run, I get `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that cor responds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON DUP LICATE KEY UPDATE`

Can anybody help me how to fix this ?

Comment: `VALUES ()` part at the end doesn't seem to be correct, huh?

Comment: VALUES is in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the insert clause on this query, between the columns and the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

```
 " INSERT INTO 
                `article` (`article`, `customer`, `price`, `a`, `b`) 
/* insert clause goes here */
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE article= VALUES(article), customer= VALUES(customer), price = VALUES(price), a = VALUES(a), b= VALUES(b)
```

Comment: I have tried adding VALUES ()-- VALUES at your commented area. But still i am getting the same result

Comment: Can you please post the entire query?

Answer (score 0):

You missed [VALUES statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) with data that actually needs to be inserted.

For instance:

```
INSERT INTO `article` (`article`, `customer`, `price`, `a`, `b`) 
VALUES ('Article name', 'Customer name', '100', 'Value of a column', 'Value of b column')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE article = VALUES(article), customer = VALUES(customer), price = VALUES(price), a = VALUES(a), b= VALUES(b)
```